# displaying values from join query array

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I have used a join query for retrieving value from two tables one is blogquestion and userdetails I wrote this query

```
$this->questions = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->select('b.question_id,b.user_id,b.question_title,b.question_tags,b.created_at,u.id,u.name')
  ->from('BlogQuestion b')
  ->leftJoin('b.UserDetails u')
  ->execute();
```

In the template iam displaying the  result using a foreach

```
<?php foreach($questions as $quest):?>

 echo $quest->getQuestionTitle() 
 echo $quest->getQuestionTags() 
 echo $quest->getName() 

<?php endforeach?>
```

title is getting from the blogquestion table and name is in usredetails table

iam getting the eerror

Unknown record property / related component "name" on "BlogQuestion"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use: `$quest->getUserdetails()->getName()` or `$quest['UserDetails']['name']`.

Comment: Thanks Crozin 

$quest['UserDetails']['name'] is working fine